# php-in-homedirs

Tags: apache2, php, lamp, webserver

I am trying to get php to work in user's public_html folder using the instructions found at:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UserDirectoryPHP

If I follow the first part and comment out the IfModule lines in php5.conf it works fine. However if I try the second part by creating a php-in-homedirs.conf file it does not work.

I have followed the instructions to the letter, multiple times, and I have never got it to work.

Is there something missing from the instructions, or does php-in-homedirs.conf just not work?

Comment: Did you follow the NEW or the OLD method? Maybe you could post your php5.conf contents?

Answer (score 0):

New method. From "Security note" onwards.

I tried it on a clean install of 13.04. But I’ve tried it on a clean 12.04 and 12.10 in the past and I’ve never got it working.

I’m beginning to doubt that it works at all.